# nvd3's x-axis broken due to one line change?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

In this live code link,

http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav

if you add `chart.yRange([0, 300])` for inverting the y-axis, the x-axis moves up
and sticks to the top(near the legend).

Any possible fix?

PS: The problem is with most of the charts on that page but 'Cumulative line chart' is closest to my use case.

Comment: What kind of chart are you talking about?

Comment: Try cumulative line chart? I tried a few and faced the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the x axis is hardcoded to `y.range()[0]` in the NVD3 source, but you can adjust this after the chart has been drawn. In your particular case, add the following code after `.call(chart)`:

```
d3.select('.nv-x.nv-axis')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + chart.yAxis.range()[1] + ')');
```